# How to show mata timestamp with laravel?

Tags: laravel

i want a meta timestamp for alle the articles when published. How do i make this automatically?

***Eksempel i use this for the articles when published to show the time when a article is published and updated:***

```
<time>{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</time>
```

**I want to making this one automatically:**

```
<p class="timestamp"><time class="format-distance-to-now" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2022-03-21T20:15:43.000Z">2022-03-21T20:15:43.000Z</time></p> </div>
```

Example with php (wordpress):

```
<time itemprop="datePublished" class="published" datetime="<?php echo get_the_time('c'); ?>" content="<?php echo get_the_time('c'); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
</time>
```

How do i make this with laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mutator or create another attribute on the post model.
e.g.

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class Post extends Model {
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

This way when using `{{ $post->created_at }}` in your blade it will render 2022-12-29 or however you want to render it.

You can also set them to dates in the model instead like so

```
public static $dates = ['updated_at', 'created_at'];
```

This way you can just do `{{ $post->created_at->format('Ymd') }}` in the blade which imo is much nicer.

e.g.

```
<time itemprop="datePublished" class="published" datetime="{{ $post->created_at->format('c') }}" content="{{ $post->created_at->format('c') }}">
    {{ $post->created_at->format('Ymd') }}
</time>
```